# Blockchain system for verifying student credentials

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts, sts-securitytokenservice

So I am new to blockchain. In fact, I am actually doing a one-year diploma for it. I found out it's incredibly hard to find accurate information online regarding blockchain. It's either a chunky mess or completely irrelevant. Right now my team's project is to work on a real-life situation where blockchain could be implemented and we chose blockchain for student credentials. We went with a Hybrid blockchain where certain personal information will be private and other stuff like credentials will be public so that educational institutes can validate them. We are supposed to be working with Hyperledger Fabric for the assignment, but we are stuck deciding whether we should be using ERC-721 Tokens or smart contracts to assign every student a unique digital asset. I am posting this here to see if I can get some help.

p.s dont mind if my concepts are completely off because its only been like a week or 2 since my classes started.

Comment: ERC-721 is an ethereum concept. In Hyperledger fabric, you can define anything as an asset. But based on your heading I think what you are looking for is Decentralized Identity. You can explore more on Indy.

Answer (score 1):

In Russia, [finance academy "Active"](https://finacademy.net/blockchain-check) already uses [Emercoin](https://emercoin.com/en) blockchain for this purpose for years. You can use Google Translate and read the [interview article](https://medium.com/@emer.rutech/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-3-2019-283dd4fb05b9).

I think, if you contact them, they will share with you their solutions and source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your use cases with [Hyperledger Indy](https://www.hyperledger.org/use/hyperledger-indy) blockchain framework. Hyperledger Indy will suit your use cases as this blockchain framework is used to manage identities.

You can visit [Indy Walkthrough](https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/sdk/en/latest/docs/getting-started/indy-walkthrough.html#indy-walkthrough) demo where you can find tutorial with code based on your use cases.

You can also check the following demo:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WZxlrGMA3s